# How to perform the summation of consecutive two digits of pairs of a given integer from a character array in c?

Tags: c

I have tried in this way->

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(void){
char number[101] = { 0 };
int isValid = 0, count = 0;

/*Input validation */
while(!isValid)
{
    count=0;
    isValid = 1;
    char *p = number;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%100s", number);

    /* Check the validity of the string */
    while(*p != '\0')
    {
        count++; //count=1
        if(!isdigit(*p))
        {
            isValid = 0;
            break;
        }
        p++;
    }

    if( !(isValid = isValid && ( count % 2 == 0 ) ) )
      printf("Please insert an even number of digits (numbers only)\n");
}
 //print the digits
 for(int i=0; i<count; i+=2)
    printf("%c%c\n", number[i], number[i+1] );
return 0;

}
```

Now the limitation has been shown here: I can show only the pair of digits of a given integer. But I could not perform the addition of these pairs?. How can I do that?.

I want to implement:
Expected Input: 123456

Expected Output: 12+34+56 = 102

Answer (score 1):

A strategy would be to concatenate the two `char` digits into a string and then converting it to an integer value using a library function like `strtol`, this will then allow you to sum the values:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
//...
long sum = 0; //to hold the sum
for (int i = 0; i < count; i += 2)
{
    long temp;
    char str[] = {number[i], number[i + 1]}; //concatenate the 2 char digits into a string
    char *endptr; //pointer to the next char after the last converted digit
    temp = strtol(str, &endptr, 10); //10, decimal conversion
    sum += temp; //add converted value
    printf("%c%c\n", number[i], number[i + 1]);
}
printf("%d", sum);
//...
```

Output:

```
12
34
56
102
```

[`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) is a very robust conversion function, much better than `atoi` because it allows you to make various input and arithmetic checks to avoid logic errors, more details in the provided link.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two issues: your array consists of pairs of characters, which you need to transform to numbers.

Let me show you one way to do this:

```
char c1, c2;
c1 = number[<whatever_index>];     // just take a character from your numbers array.
c2 = number[<whatever_index> + 1]; // just take the next character from your array.
int i1 = c1 - '0';                 // Like this, you can transform a character to an integer;
int i2 = c2 - '0';                 // idem dito :-)
int i = 10*i1 + i2;                // how to you "append" two digits into an integer number?
```

From here, you can calculate your sum.

**Edit, after having read the answer from Anastaciu**

There are indeed two ways to do this: either you concatenate two characters and convert the result into an integer, or you convert two characters into integers and use a mathematical way to "concatenate" them.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 ways - convert the character pairs to integer, find the sum with integers, then convert the resulting integer back into characters (inside `printf()`); or keep it as characters and find the sum with characters. The other answers both use the first way (converting to/from integer).

The second way might look like:

```
    // Create some variables to store the sum as 3 chars

    char low = '0';
    char mid = '0';
    char high = '0';

    // Add pairs of digits to the sum

    for(int i=0; i < count; i += 2) {
        low += number[i+1] - '0';
        if(low > '9') {
            low -= 10;
            mid++;
        }
        mid += number[i] - '0';
        if(mid > '9') {
            mid -= 10;
            high++;
        }
    }

    // Output the resulting characters (with leading zeros suppressed)

    if(high != '0') {
        putchar(high);
        putchar(mid);
    } else if(mid != '0') {
        putchar(mid);
    }
    putchar(low);
```